# how to store files into mongodb using django without gridfs?

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I am new to working with mongodb and django. I need to know how to stores files into mongodb with the help of django, using the djongo engine. Can anyone help me?

I tried using FileField() and setting up the url path. there was no errors yet i couldn't find the file in the db